# Need a contact form that allows users to choose who the email goes to based on what they select from a drop down list

Tags: php, dropdown, contact-form

New to PHP. Im working on a contact from that needs to allow users to select who they want their message to go to based on options from a drop down list. The form i currently have works to send to one user, however I am having trouble getting it to work with the list. I have tried using if else, but no luck. Where and how do I insert the list in the PHP code?

Here is the HTML part of my code:

```
<select id="topic" name="Topic">
<option value="billing">Billing</option>
<option value="careers">Careers</option>
<option value="pickup">Pick up</option>
<option value="sales">Sales</option>
<option value="other">Tracing</option>
</select>

<form id="reused_form">
<div class="form-group">
  <label >Name</label>
  <input type="text" name="name" required class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Name">
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <label >Email</label>
  <input type="email" name="email" required class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Email">
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <label >Phone Number</label>
  <input type="number" name="number" required class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Phone Number">
 </div>
 
 <div class="form-group">
  <label >Message</label>
  <textarea rows="3" name="message" class="form-control" placeholder="Type Your Message">   </textarea>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <button class="btn btn-raised btn-lg btn-warning w3-theme" type="submit">Send</button>
</div>
</form>
                            
<div id="error_message" style="width:100%; height:100%; display:none; ">
  <h4> Error </h4> Sorry there was an error sending your form. 
</div>
<div id="success_message" style="width:100%; height:100%; display:none; ">

  <h2 style="color:blue;">Success! Your Message was Sent Successfully.</h2>
</div>
```

This is the PHP code:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

require_once './vendor/autoload.php';

use FormGuide\Handlx\FormHandler;


$pp = new FormHandler(); 

$validator = $pp->getValidator();
$validator->fields(['name','email','number'])->areRequired()->maxLength(50);
$validator->field('email')->isEmail();
$validator->field('comments')->maxLength(6000);

if($topic == 'billing') { /if billing was selected
$to = 'email@gmail.com';
 }
else if($topic == 'pickup') /other options
$to = 'email@gmail.com'; 
}
else if($topic == 'sales') /other options
$to = 'email@gmail.com'; 


$pp->sendEmailTo('email@gmail.com'); // ← Your email here*/

echo $pp->process($_POST);
```

Comment: You said you already try `if else`, can you post the code that you tried so we can identify the problem.

Comment: I have updated the code to what i was trying, any help is appreciated. thank you!

Comment: "I am having trouble getting it to work" - please be more precise: what exactly happens instead of the desired behavior? did you do any debugging?

Comment: You should not create a prolonged if-elseif-…-else chain for stuff like this to begin with. Put your recipient emails into an array, use the values of your select option as the key, and the email as the value. Then you simply check if the passed option value exists as key in that array - `if(isset($foo[$_POST['Topic']])) { /* work with $foo[$_POST['Topic']] here */ }`

Comment: Hi, where in the code would I add the array?